# How do I wrap a new div around a specific row?

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to find the right selector to use to wrap a new div with class around one specific row. The challenge is that none of the rows have unique identifiers.

```
<div id="message-board-forum">
<div class="table-wrapper">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

`$("#message-board-forum > div.table-wrapper > div.row:nth-child(1)").wrap('div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"');`

The above jQuery is not pulling any errors, but when the page processes the first row is not being wrapped in

```
<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>');
```

OR

```
.wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper">');
```

You need add `<` and `>` to wrap your div tag.

> ## .wrap()
>
> Using .wrap(), we can insert an HTML structure around the inner  elements like so:
>
> `$( ".inner" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );`
>
> The new  element is created on the fly and added to the DOM. The result is a new  wrapped around each matched element:
>
> REF: https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```js
/*

$("#message-board-forum > div.table-wrapper > div.row:nth-child(1)").wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>');

$("#message-board-forum > div.table-wrapper > div.row:first-child").wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>');

$("div.table-wrapper .row").first().wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>');

$(".table-wrapper .row").first().wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>');

*/
```

```css
.forum-toolbar-wrapper {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message-board-forum">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="row">11</div>
    <div class="row">22</div>
    <div class="row">33</div>
    <div class="row">44</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(".table-wrapper .row").first().wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>');
</script>
```

Comment: '$("#message-board-forum > div.table-wrapper > div.row:nth-child(1)").wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>');'    -->Still not wrapping the first row in the div/class.'

Comment: @MikeRapp which one are wrapped? in your local version

Comment: None are wrapped.

Comment: @MikeRapp your id `message-board-forum` this is unique right?

Comment: @MikeRapp ok try this `$("div.table-wrapper .row").first().wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>');`

Comment: @MikeRapp what jQuery version you are using? I can't reproduce your bug

Comment: I had tried your latest method earlier, again, the row doesn't end up wrapped in that div/class. Using jQ 1.7

Comment: @MikeRapp Ok if this one is not working (`$(".row").wrap('<div class="forum-toolbar-wrapper"></div>');`), means something wrong with the setup, not the code.

Comment: @MikeRapp try to post all your html and css and js you have

Comment: I'm not eligible to move this discussion to chat. If you'd like to continue this discussion off-site, I'd be happy tog give you my contact info. Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: @MikeRapp one last thing, the code snippet here works in your browsers?

Comment: I'm actually trying to run this on a live page, with about a dozen other calls that are working properly. This is running on a cms that uses v1.7. Mjrapp@gmail.com

Comment: @MikeRapp try hard reload the browser maybe, I really couldn't think of any other problem could stop jquery running `.wrap()`, it can only be order of the script etc, try to debug make sure you can use jquery do something to the element. Are those element generated dynamically or generated after?

Comment: Given that this is an intranet site, I can't share a link publicly. But if you email me I will get you in.